# Significance of maxThreads in Tomcat, can this limit be breached, if yes then what happens to subsequent request

Tags: tomcat7

There is a maxThreads attribute in server.xml, when and how does it comes into effect.

I know that current tomcat threads can be seen by executing.
*ps -eLf | grep tomcat*

How the server responds to subsequent client requests when the count of above command exceeds maxThreads ?

Answer (score 0):

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

> Each incoming request requires a thread for the duration of that request. If more simultaneous requests are received than can be handled by the currently available request processing threads, additional threads will be created up to the configured maximum (the value of the maxThreads attribute). If still more simultaneous requests are received, they are stacked up inside the server socket created by the Connector, up to the configured maximum (the value of the acceptCount attribute). Any further simultaneous requests will receive "connection refused" errors, until resources are available to process them.